# Excel -> SP List with correct column types?

Tags: list, excel, import

Are there solutions available for importing an Excel to SharePoint with SharePoint column types? Or has someone tried this with the help of OpenXml (with a custom import web part with default values, for example)? Or should I somehow combine existing oob features with something extra?

The problem I see with pure SharePoint is:
- Import from Excel does not support SharePoint column types
- Copy-paste using datasheet provides bad error messages (ie 1 letter wrong in 1 excel cell causes an error which is very time-consuming to solve: "error occurred in one of 1000000 cells you tried to import. Please try to find the error. Have a nice day!")